# Difference between OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor and OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-orm

Spring Boot is configured to automatically use `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor`. I do have a `HandlerInterceptor` that access JPA and I need it to run after `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor`, but I can't configure it this way.

So I configured `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` and in this way my `HandlerInterceptor` can access JPA, however I have both `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor` and `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` configured.

What is the difference between that filter and interceptor?

What would be the problem to have both active?

Is there a better way to have my interceptor allowed to access JPA?